# Can i create multiple company with different application under one google cloud account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have 2 companies with different application and function. But they share same customer database. Should i create one google cloud account and create 2 seperate project or should i using 2 google account for 2 companies?

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of the structure or nature of the work but if you take the scenario of you being a freelancer and creating two projects that happen to use the same DB (lets say owned by you or someone else), I would do the following:

3 projects in total under 3 different Organizations.

Each company will have there own ORG with their own project/application (Project A & B).

Then the third project(Project C) contains the DB they are using, couple of reasons why this useful:

- You can grant each project different access/roles to the DB allowing them to do specific queries, limit resources, track costs, or even force costs onto Projects A & B.
- You could instead set up an API in Project C that handles all needed DB interactions and give those Endpoints to Projects A & B.

Unsure what you meant about Google Cloud Account but this normally refers to the individual as in johndoe@gmail.com. You can have access to all three projects with one account and then get removed by admins once the work is done. Similarly you can great all three projects and then transfer them to their respective ORGs after but that is slightly more complicated and can cause issues.

Comment: about my company structure, My company have its own application. I have another joint venture company with another company. and its has its own application. However, client will be manage by my company. What different between project and organisation are you mention above?

Comment: This isn't really a question for stack at the moment but I suggest you read into Organizations and Project structures. In short an ORG is like a domain, you have one domain that houses all of your projects. ORGs allow you to set policies on resources and etc.. https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/how-to